# Generate (and save in disk) Image from "random" byte array

Tags: c#, image

I am building a block of information that in the end is converted to byte array. 
I was wondering if it would be possible to convert it into an image?

I know that in the end it would not "display nothing" with meaning, it would be a more abstract result, and this is exactly what I am looking for.

I've tried the following code, but it returns an exception...:

```
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are currently trying to parse a random byte array as if it contains a complete valid image file, including valid headers for some image format. Your byte array most likely does not contain such headers, and therefore cannot be parsed as an image. Try something like this instead:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    int size = (int)Math.Sqrt(byteArrayIn.Length); // Some bytes will not be used as we round down here

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(size, size, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

    try
    {
        // Copy byteArrayIn to bitmapData row by row (to account for the case
        // where bitmapData.Stride != bitmap.Width)
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < bitmapData.Height; ++rowIndex)
            Marshal.Copy(byteArrayIn, rowIndex * bitmap.Width, bitmapData.Scan0 + rowIndex * bitmapData.Stride, bitmap.Width);
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve your block of information use a lossless image format like a bmp with rgb values.

You will have to init bmp height and width with a value large enough to store all your byteArrayIn. Since rgb value is 3 bytes you have to divide the byteArrayIn size by 3 to get your number of pixels and then find a rectangle size to fit that number of pixels.  For instance if byteArrayIn is 312000 bytes long :

312000 / 3 = 104000 pixel (so you can use 208 x 500 pixel bitmap)

You may need to add filler data if the biteArrayIn size is not a multiple of 3 or if you want your bmp to be a certain size.

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/559268/howplustoplusconvertplusbyteplusarrayplusRGBplusim) for sample code.

Answer (score -2):

You must to generate a byte array, but you must know that the first bytes of a file (or image) usually determine the type of file, then, you must generate first "header bytes" and after add random bytes. 
The type and order and meaning of "header bytes" depends of type of file or image, for example:

```
JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9.
```

Extracted from Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29